# Get all items in folders and subfolders in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table set up to hold folders. Each folder has an `ID`, a `ParentID` and a couple other columns.

```
  ID | ParentID | Name
   1    Null      Base Folder
   2    1         Folder 1
   3    2         Folder 2

   etc
```

I'm working on a delete function but I'm running into issues getting everything nested inside a folder. Things can be nested ad infinitum.

So if I run my query on `Base Folder` I'd want to delete `Base Folder`, `Folder 1`, and `Folder 2`

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Are these folders that exist on the file system? If so, why are you redundantly storing the information about them in the database, when you can derive these at run time so easily using CLR?

Comment: These folders are being used to store projects on a website. 

As each user logs in, they'll have access to their own file system which they can create/delete/move folders to store their projects in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `ON DELETE CASCADE` :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Just make sure you read this carefully and are sure this is the behavior you want.

Comment: After a little bit of tinkering with the structure this works perfectly. Thanks!